# Good practice when working with multiple solutions of a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I have a system of nonlinear equations. I want to do some comparative statistics and I want to plot the results from the statistical computations. I have two questions about good practice on manipulating the solution lists.

1. What is the best practice for selecting the results from solving a system of equations without calling `Solve` multiple times?
2. When more than one solution for the same variable is available, how do I select values from the according to a given criterion; for example, the highest value?

The best example I could come up is:

```
EQ1[c_] := x - 0.5 - ((0.8*(z - 0.5))/(y - 0.5 - 0.8*(z - 0.5)))*(y - 0.5);
EQ2[c_] := 1 - x - y - z;
EQ3[c_] := 0.8*(z - c)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 - 0.8*(-c)^2
SYSTEM = {EQ1[c], EQ2[c], EQ3[c]};
Table[
  {c, Solve[SYSTEM == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}]}, 
  {c, 0.24, 0.28, 0.01}]
```

> ```
> {{0.24, {{x -> 0.0380158, y -> 0.48276, z -> 0.479225}, 
>          {x -> 0.291508, y -> 0.326764, z -> 0.381728}}},  
>  {0.25, {{x -> 0.309524, y -> 0.309524, z -> 0.380952}, 
>          {x -> ComplexInfinity, y -> 0.5, z -> 0.5}}},  
>  {0.26, {{x -> 0.324093, y -> 0.294404, z -> 0.381503}}},  
>  {0.27, {{x -> 0.33648, y -> 0.280628, z -> 0.382892}}},  
>  {0.28, {{x -> 0.347344, y -> 0.267788, z -> 0.384868}}}}
> ```

Now that we have the example, I will go back to my questions:

1. What is the best practice for building a table such that I can easily plot the results afterwards? The way I would do, which is really inefficient, is:

   ```
   Tablex = 
     Table[
       {c, Solve[SYSTEM == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}][[1,1,2]]}, 
       {c, 0.24, 0.28, 0.01}]
   Tabley =
     Table[
       {c, Solve[SYSTEM == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}][[1,2,2]]}, 
       {c, 0.24, 0.28, 0.01}]
   Tablez = 
     Table[
       {c, Solve[SYSTEM == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}][[1,3,2]]}, 
       {c, 0.24, 0.28, 0.01}]
   ```
2. We can see that for `c <= 0.25` we have two possible solutions. How can we  create a rule that, for example, always looks for the highest value of the first variable? I can see the results are in ascending order, therefore, I could get the highest value for all `c` such that `c <= 0.25`
   with

   ```
   Solve[SYSTEM == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}][[2,1,2]]
   ```

But if the parameters change, this threshold will change and so I would like my code to pick itself the highest `x` in the case of multiple solutions.

Comment: How do you want the case `x -> ComplexInfinity` to be handled?

Comment: First: thank you for the edits. We can ignore the ComplexInfinity case, m_goldberg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the results you show for your example and see if we can't exact the values you want from that list.

```
data = 
  {{0.24, {{x -> 0.0380158, y -> 0.48276, z -> 0.479225}, 
           {x -> 0.291508, y -> 0.326764, z -> 0.381728}}},  
   {0.25, {{x -> 0.309524, y -> 0.309524, z -> 0.380952}, 
           {x -> ComplexInfinity, y -> 0.5, z -> 0.5}}},  
   {0.26, {{x -> 0.324093, y -> 0.294404, z -> 0.381503}}},  
   {0.27, {{x -> 0.33648, y -> 0.280628, z -> 0.382892}}},  
   {0.28, {{x -> 0.347344, y -> 0.267788, z -> 0.384868}}}}

{cVals, solns} = Transpose[data];
{xVals, yVals, zVals} = 
   Transpose[({x, y, z} /. MaximalBy[#, #[[1, 2]] &] & /@ solns)[[All, 1]]];

 xVals
```

> `{0.291508, ComplexInfinity, 0.324093, 0.33648, 0.347344}`

```
 yVals
```

> `{0.326764, 0.5, 0.294404, 0.280628, 0.267788}`

```
 zVals
```

> `{0.381728, 0.5, 0.381503, 0.382892, 0.384868}`

The complex infinity value at `c = .25` will cause trouble when plotting `x` against `c`. You need to come up with a policy to handle infinite results. But, ignoring that for the moment, here is a plot.

```
ListLinePlot[{xVals, yVals, zVals},
  DataRange -> {.24, .28},
  PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: plot]

The main point of this answer is not in the details of the expression manipulations I used; rather, it is that is good practice to solve the system of equations once and manipulate the expression returned.

#### Update

BTW, when I set up your equations in the way I think they should be set up, I get very different results from those you present.

```
EQ1 = x - 0.5 - ((0.8*(z - 0.5))/(y - 0.5 - 0.8*(z - 0.5)))*(y - 0.5) == 0;
EQ2 = 1 - x - y - z == 0;
EQ3[c_] := 0.8*(z - c)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 - 0.8*c^2 == 0
SYSTEM = EQ1 && EQ2 && EQ3[c];
solns = 
  Quiet @ Table[
    Solve[SYSTEM && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}] // Chop, 
    {c, 0.24, 0.28, 0.01}]
```

> ```
> {{{x -> 0.0380158, y -> 0.48276, z -> 0.479225}, 
>   {x -> 0.291508, y -> 0.326764, z -> 0.381728}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}}, 
>  {{x -> 0.309524, y -> 0.309524, z -> 0.380952}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0.5}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}}, 
>  {{x -> 0.324093, y -> 0.294404, z -> 0.381503}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}}, 
>  {{x -> 0.33648, y -> 0.280628, z -> 0.382892}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}}, 
>  {{x -> 0.347344,y -> 0.267788, z -> 0.384868}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, z -> 0}}}
> ```

#### Update 2

This update addresses an issue raised by the OP in comments to this answer.

To eliminate solutions where `(x - 0.5)/(y - 0.5)` is not well-defined, I will delete solutions where `y -> 0.5` appears before selecting the solutions with maximal `x` value.

```
{xVals, yVals, zVals} = 
  Transpose[
    ({x, y, z} /. MaximalBy[#, #[[1, 2]] &] & /@ 
      DeleteCases[solns, {_, y -> _?(# == .5 &), _}, {2}])[[All, 1]]];
```

Then

```
ListLinePlot[{xVals, yVals, zVals},
  DataRange -> {.24, .28},
  PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have been learning a lot on this community. Your answers in particular are outstanding.

Comment: Regarding your edit, what I am finding odd is that if I copy and paste your code, I still get only the first roots you showed there. I am not sure why that happens.

Comment: I am impressed that I indeed cannot see the other roots like you showed in your Edit. Any idea of why? `{{{x -> 0.0380158, y -> 0.48276, z -> 0.479225}, {x -> 0.291508, 
   y -> 0.326764, z -> 0.381728}}, {{x -> 0.309524, y -> 0.309524, 
   z -> 0.380952}, {x -> ComplexInfinity, y -> 0.5, 
   z -> 0.5}}, {{x -> 0.324093, y -> 0.294404, 
   z -> 0.381503}}, {{x -> 0.33648, y -> 0.280628, 
   z -> 0.382892}}, {{x -> 0.347344, y -> 0.267788, z -> 0.384868}}}`

Comment: @LauraK. What version of Mathematica are you using? I solved the system using V11.1.1.

Comment: Good point! 10.3.1.0. I will try to see if I can update it.

Comment: Yes, now I can see the other roots. But this brings another problem, because now I don't want the largest root, but the second largest (I want to ignore the (0.5,0.5,0) result).

Comment: @LauraK. You need to be careful when formulating criteria. Are you don't want to eliminated solutions where `z` is 0 and then select the solutions with the largest `x` value?

Comment: I do want to select the solutions with the largest `x` value, indeed. But, for simplicity, I've omitted something in the example. I have a multiplier for a nonlinear constraint that is given by (x-0.5)/(y-0.5). Therefore, (0.5,0.5,0) is not a possible solution. I can handle this by changing the range in which I solve (x,y,z) but it would not be general, but for this specific formulation.

Comment: @LauraK. So wouldn't my suggestion  -- eliminating the solutions where `z` is zero -- work? It's very easy to implement. I can show you how.

Comment: In this example, and from the top of my mind I think for most of my problems it would work. But a better thing to do would actually remove the solutions such that (x-0.5)/(y-0.5) is not well defined. Do you have any idea on how to do that, @m_goldberg?

Comment: @LauraK. I have updated my answer to address the issue of eliminating solution where `(x - 0.5)/(y - 0.5)` is not well defined.

Comment: Oh uau, @m_goldberg: thank you! If I could, I would like to triple vote your answer :)